# How to use Runtime

Tags: java, runtime-error

Im trying to learn how to use `Runtime` in Java, netbeans but when I try to call an application different to notepad the compiler stops in the first space. I dont find the problem, its the simplest code ever:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaApplication2 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try{

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("TI30886800A(C:)/Archivos de Programa/DitelCapture/DitelCaptureV4.4");
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();   
    }
}

}
```

I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "TI30886800A(C:)/Archivos": CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo (The system couldnt found the specified file).
```

(Also, I'll need to put `.exe` at the end of every application I want to open?)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation of your file location.

Comment: Give the absolute path of the executable file

Comment: Have you tried escaping the spaces in the file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filepath:

```
"TI30886800A(C:)/Archivos de Programa/DitelCapture/DitelCaptureV4.4"
```

doesn't look much like a Filepath because of `TI30886800A`. The syntax of the Filepath you're trying to execute is this (you'll have to use escaped quotes because there's spaces in the filepath):

```
public static void executeCommand() {
    try {
        Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start filename.exe, null, new File("\"C:/Archivos de Programa/DitelCapture/DitelCaptureV4.4\""));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And also you don't specify the file inside that directory that you want to be executed, that could also be the problem

Comment: You're correct, I used the wrong file path, it works now, thank you!

Comment: @IgnacioMtzDeSalinasUreta no problem man. Just choose the answer that best solved your problem so we can close the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Use (escaped) quotes to work around the spaces

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"TI30886800A(C:)/Archivos de Programa/DitelCapture/DitelCaptureV4.4\"");
```

Comment: Thank you! Works with the new path

Answer (score 0):

This

```
"TI30886800A(C:)/Archivos de Programa/DitelCapture/DitelCaptureV4.4"
```

Doesn't look like a correct file path.

You probably need something like:

```
"C:\\Archivos de Programa\\DitelCapture\\DitelCaptureV4.4"
```

Drop the "TI30886800A" and the parenthesis around C:.

Why is the path like that?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I used the incorrect path I thought I could used the spanish direction but it has to be like this: C:\Program Files (x86)\DitelCapture.